# Is there an App for determining the current capacity of an Apple watch battery?

Tags: battery, apple-watch

I see from Mactracker that a new battery has a capacity of 205 mAh (38mm Apple Watch Series 1). For the MBP and iPhones I have used coconutBattery to show the decay in battery capacity over the lifetimes. Is there a similar tool for the watch?

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Answer (score 1):

No - neither is there a public API for apps to do this on any iOS device. Clearly there are [private API (heres one version for iOS / not watchOS)](https://github.com/ethan605/ios-battery-stat) and occasionally someone slips an app by review knowing full well that's against the rules - but they generally get pulled quickly or fail to work / crash.

- [Is there an iPhone app (as opposed to desktop software) that shows actual battery cycles - cycles number](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298750/is-there-an-iphone-app-as-opposed-to-desktop-software-that-shows-actual-batter)