# Is there an iPhone app (as opposed to desktop software) that shows actual battery cycles - cycles number

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, battery

I can use Coconut Battery on my Macbook which shows cycles number on my iPhone when I plug iPhone into Macbook. I don't want to use that however. I want to have an iPhone app for that. Do you know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a very long time, the [API for that information is private](https://github.com/ethan605/ios-battery-stat). Any apps on the App Store that manage to trick review or access private API generally get shut down by Apple review / oversight in days or weeks.

The official way to get that data is through Apple Support.

- https://support.apple.com
- https://www.apple.com/batteries/service-and-recycling/

Until and unless Apple decides to provide cycle count detail in the settings app for iOS or in a public API, you will likely need a trusted computer and / or jailbreak to get those details.

- [How do I check an iOS device's battery health?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47974/how-to-figure-out-ios-device-battery-health)